# COM+ "Enable Partitions" Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, com

Windows 7 Pro, 32-bit... when I go into Component Services and expand computers and right-click on My Computer and choose properties, the Options tab has a disabled *Enable partitions* option that I have not been able to figure out how to enable. Windows 7 'help' indicates that it can be available (by virtue of not saying anything to the contrary), nor can I found any security/group policy setting to enable/disable this.

The [only thing I've found on Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688501(v=vs.85).aspx) about documents it as not being available only for WinXP and Win2000 (again suggesting that Win7 should be good).

Any thoughts or ideas? It's always possible that it's not available on Windows 7, but I've not even found anything that confirms this either.

(might be worth noting that this same question's been [asked over in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947782/component-services-enable-partitions-disabled) a few months ago by a different user, but has attracted little activity. I'm thinking this community may be a better forum for this query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible answer; according to: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a601d45a-10c0-4da9-a424-d35afef22161/how-to-enable-windows-7-windows-8-com-partitions-function

I'll quote in it's entirity:

> According to the Product team on this behavior, starting from Windows
>   Vista, they have the “Enable Partitions” checkbox grayed out on client
>   desktops. This was an intentional change as they want the ability to
>   have COM+ partitions to be available only on servers and not client
>   desktops.

...which makes me wonder why the blazes the checkbox is there in the first place if there's never going to be a way to enabled it.